# cocoa application crash log debug vs release

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am new to cococa learning. A crash log is generated whever a cocoa os x program crahses. Whether the program was a debug build or release in both cases it is generated. What exactly is the difference in the crash log contents for two builds of same app when they crash ? Is the crash log of debug build program has more information ? if so, what information does it contain which release crash log does not.
Thanks,

Comment: "Symbols", I would say, which gives you a meaningful stacktrace.  In the release version you will have to *Symbolicate* in order to get a meaningful stacktrace.

Comment: No, it's done when you receive a crash log.  It contains addresses, and you use the archive produced by Xcode along with a command line tool in order to get a meaningful stacktrace from the crash log.  You can then start looking for the bug.  With a debug build you get symbols straight away within needing to symbolicate.